# Kali Linux 2022 freezes on login on Mac

Tags: linux, boot, mac, virtualbox, freeze

I recently downloaded Kali Linux 2022 on virtual box 6.1 on MacBookPro 32GB ram, everything was working fine until yesterday I notice that Linux slows down and lags when I use Firefox, I tried to increase the speed manually by increasing swappiness from 1 to 10 (I am using kali on 4GB ram) maybe that is what affected Linux. I  also installed preload. `sudo apt-get install preload`.

Now when I try to log in it stuck in the username or sometime in the password that I have to turn off by force quit (Linux Aborted).
I can't go to ctrl+alt+ f1-f6 no matter how many times I press it.
I can't press E to open grub-parameters in Grub.

I have already searched many forums and videos all solutions are for windows users, not for Mac users.
Please suggest to me what I need to do to resolve this matter